# How can I solve the unlock address issue?

Tags: web3js

I created the address and unlocked the address when it is created.

```
var address = response.substring(2).toLowerCase();
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address, pwd, 300);
```

Once created, I sent ether to other address.
It worked at that time.

After that, I restart the wallet and I can't resend ether.

Error is following.

`error Error: Returned error: authentication needed: password or unlock`

In this case, how can I do?

If I did't restart the wallet, will it work in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "300" in the "unlockAccount" call specifies the duration of the unlock, which is 300 seconds. That's why the ether sending didn't work afterwards.

You will have to unlock it again, after the expiry, or restart. You may pass in "0", which will unlock until the next restart. However, that's not recommended, for obvious security risk.